# Cannot repair member file - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dll, sfc

I have a Dell laptop in front of me running Windows 7. the main problem is that when I click "computer" from the start menu trying to find a file on the (C:) drive Windows Explorer crashes. Also these computers are in a domain. When the person who uses this computer daily logs in, windows explorer crashes and loops. So I ran a virus scan and malware scan and neither produced significant results. So then I ran SFC /Scan in the command prompt and it looks like there are some damaged .dll files. I'm stuck here. I'm not sure what to do next. I have posted the sfc details below.

There were a very good amount of files that were repaired but below are the oddball weird ones that showed up in the list.

> 2015-11-24 10:53:37, Info                  CSI    00000195 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-WindowsCodec, Version = 7.1.7601.18135, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1
>   nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral,
>   TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-11-24 10:53:39, Info                  CSI    00000198 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-WindowsCodec, Version = 7.1.7601.18135, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1
>   nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral,
>   TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-11-24 10:53:39, Info                  CSI    00000199 [SR] This
>   component was referenced by
>   [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2836502~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.2836502-2_neutral_GDR"
>   2015-11-24 10:53:39, Info                  CSI    0000019c [SR] Could
>   not reproject corrupted file
>   [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32"[l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll";
>   source file in store is also corrupted
>
> 2015-11-24 11:03:17, Info                  CSI    00000320 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-WindowsCodec, Version = 7.1.7601.18135, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1
>   nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral,
>   TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-11-24 11:03:17, Info                  CSI    00000322 [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-WindowsCodec, Version = 7.1.7601.18135, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1
>   nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral,
>   TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
>
> 2015-11-24 11:03:17, Info                  CSI    00000323 [SR] This
>   component was referenced by
>   [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2836502~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.2836502-2_neutral_GDR"
>
> 2015-11-24 11:03:17, Info                  CSI    00000326 [SR] Could
>   not reproject corrupted file
>   [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32"[l:34{17}]"WindowsCodecs.dll";
>   source file in store is also corrupted

Comment: *If the source file in the store is corrupt, provide the SFC tool, a different source store.*  In other words download a Windows 7 .ISO, extract the install.wim image, then point SFC to that extract image.  Honestly though given the amount of corruption I have serious doubts you will be able to accomplish that, so it might just be best, to cut your loses and install a fresh instance of Windows 7 again.  I would put money that your system drive is about to completely fail on you.

Comment: Those specific files are not even in the WinSxS what I suggest would only fix hose that are. `WindowsCodecs.dll` belongs to some other package that you have to install manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run regedit.exe, go to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component
>   Based
>   Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_microsoft-windows-windowscodec_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_167a48aba1a5cb67

and on the right side you see some text. Look here for the version `7.1.7601.18135` ad look under `Name` which KB number you see in the text "Package_for_KBxxxxxx". Now use [control panel to uninstall the update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-update) with this KB number.

If this doesn't work and removing also fails, do the following. Download the MSU file for this KB from the [downloadcenter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/default.aspx), put the [MSU into the folder %SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption.aspx) and run the [checksur tool KB947821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821).

Comment: This worked! the uninstall of the updated made everything stop crashing!

Comment: Nice to hear this. can you please tell me which KB number it was?